# How to identify deleted transactions in the Netsuite Transactions table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, netsuite

I'm working on building reports outside of NetSuite (in order to join this data with data from other source systems) using data pulled into Redshift from the NetSuite back-end tables. I have several tables that have been completely piped into Redshift against which I write my queries. In trying to recreate some values from the monthly P&Ls, I noticed my totals were not tying out with what is shown in the NS UI. After troubleshooting with our finance team, it appears as they there are 3 invoices that they deleted but are still showing up in the Transactions table. I do not as an IsDeleted field or something similar. How can I identify which records in the table have been deleted in order to filter them out of my results?

Comment: How often is your data pulled into Redshift? And what does your ETL process look like?  If you are using a service like Fivetran or Stitch, records are never deleted.

Comment: Otherwise, you can query the System_notes table to access all record creations, modifications, updates and deletions.

Comment: We're using Airflow and Spark to bring the data into Redshift hourly. The System_notes table seems to be exactly what I've been looking for though. Thanks!

Comment: hey @sawyer i finally got access to the System_notes table and can't find what field would lead me to deleted records. The Operation field seems like that would be the one but I only see values of Changed, Created, Unset, and Set. I thought "Unset" might be it but does not appear to be. What field should I be using to find deleted records?

Answer (score 4):

For Transactions has other posters have said use deleted records but a word to the wise here, deleted record only track the transactions themselves. Therefore, if your end users delete some lines in your transactions, deleted record WONT show said transactions in deleted records.

Some commenter said to look in system notes but in our cases, we only have the new and old version_id for the type impact in the system notes. Moreover, we never found a way to get what it mapped to on the ODBC side. (Correct me if I am wrong I would be more than happy to get a better way that the shitty hack we found)

The only workaround we found in our process here is to load all transactions with last_modified_date > {ts'last Import date'} in a temporary table and check if some lines for those transactions were deleted. In addition, to looking into deleted record to find the deleted transactions themselves. That is the only way we were able to match for our P&L reports long therm. 
The logic behind this is that luckily in our processes, the end user must always edit the transaction themselves to delete some lines. Therefore, when they save their changes the transaction itself get a new modified date.

We asked NetSuite support directly and they told us that they do not officially have an official table to track the deletions of lines.

Comment: I ended up speaking with a NetSuite consultant who pretty much told me the same thing. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a saved search of deleted records(record type of invoice) in NetSuite. Export it via CSV or Excel then use this CSV/Excel to update Redshift table and tag deleted record.

In the future you can create an API call to Redshift(if available) when a NetSuite record got deleted that will update/tag the deleted record in Redshift. This way you don't need to generate the deleted record.

Comment: Interesting. So there is no field anywhere within the NetSuite schema that denotes whether a record has been deleted in the front end?

Comment: Once the record got deleted it is totally deleted. That is why NetSuite created a Deleted Record saved search. This saved search will tell you who, when, context(UI, User Event, Scheduled etc.) of the record once it got deleted. In your case, you might want to filter the saved search with context = user interface(I assume when you say front end you mean user interface)

Comment: Ah that's interesting. In speaking with my finance team, they said 3 invoices were deleted in the UI. I still see these transactions in the transactions table, however. I was expecting to find some indicator field in a table I could link to to determine which records had been deleted (in the UI). I would imagine they have to be recorded and stored somewhere for the Deleted Record saved search to find them though, right?

Comment: Can you ask them if they deleted it or just void the transaction? If they void it, the transaction will be there but it will not have any GL impact.

Comment: I had our finance user confirm that the transactions were completely deleted. They no longer appear in the client transaction listing whereas she said that if they would have been voided, they would show there with a value of $0.00 and be denoted as "Voided"

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` is logged in `TRANSACTION_HISTORY`